# PowerShell - read only wildcard file names i have specified in dir and output results to a txt file oddities

Tags: powershell

I have a small problem when using PowerShell to output a txt file with a list of files names in a directory with the word file appended to the start of each line(file dave.acc). When i use this one liner at a prompt`(foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem .\*.aac) {echo "file '$i'" | Out-File -encoding ascii mylist.txt}` i only have one entry in my new text file after this is run (seems to be just the last entry in the dir. There is five files in the dir and my expected output in my new txt file should read file

```
file dave.mp3 
file steve.mp3
```

etc etc any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, for each file corresponding to your filter, you overwrite "mylist.txt".

Try :

```
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem .\*.aac) {
Add-Content .\mylist.txt "file $i"
}
```

Add-Content will append new content to your file for each file in your Get-ChildItem output. :)

**Edit :**

Also, you should not use "echo" which is an alias of "Write-Output". If you don't want to use "Add-Content" you can do :

```
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem .\*.aac) {
Write-Output "file $i" | Out-File -encoding ascii -Append .\mylist.txt
}
```

But as you can see, it is longer to write. :)

"Add-Content" essentially do the ascii encoding and the "Append" option by default.*

****edit**: It's true for PS 5.1 but not for PS 7 which default the encoding to UTF-8 as @zett42 mentioned it in the comments.*

Comment: Thanks Juste the reason i used pipe to out-file was because the encoding of the file was Unicode and i just wanted UTF8, again thanks.

Comment: @bjammin898 Yup, that's why I gave you the "Add-Content" method.
Have a good day. :)

Comment: @zett42 That's right! I will mention that. I mostly use Windows PS (5.1).